# Select all cities in Germany from city and country layers?

Tags: qgis, postgresql, query, references, germany

I have 2 layers:

- `"layer_1"`: countries of Europe
- `"layer_2"`: cities of Europe

I want to create (and then save) a `"layer_3"` which would be all the cities of Germany.

Is there any good tutorial of how can I write spatial queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could find some interesting information in this [tutorial book](http://http-server.carleton.ca/~dmckie/%28Andrea%20Blindenbacher,%20Oct.%2021,%202012%29%20QGIS%20Tutorial_SyringesNearParks.pdf) It is recent enough (Fall 2012)

If your data is stored in PostGIS you could look at [this tutorial](http://manual.linfiniti.com/en/postgis/spatial_queries.html)

For your specific needs, look in your shapefile city database if there is descriptive info about the country. If not use the spatial plugin in Menu/Vector/Spatial Query and do a query with intersect or within